How to make text link to URL, Figure, Bibliography and Images

How to create these kind of links as I show in the picture?
This is the code I'm working on
\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

%ND
%\includegraphics{universe}


\title{My First LaTeX Document}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{October 15, 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Although there is a lot of flexibility in terms of what and how 
you write in each section, there are guidelines %First Link% 
that shoud be followed.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Usually, research papers flow from the general to the specific 
and back to the general in their organization. The introduction uses 
a general-to-specific movement in its organization, establishing the 
thesis and setting the context for the conversation. The methods and 
results sections are more detailed and specific, providing support 
for the generalizations made in the introduction. The discussion 
section moves toward an increasingly more general discussion of the 
subject, leading to the conclusions and recommendations, which then 
generalize the conversation again.

\section{Instructions}

Given that this is just a tryout, don’t include an Abstract in 
the document. Use the default font type for the class article, but 
with a font size of 11 pts.


\subsection{Figures}

In case you include figures or diagrams, they should make sense, 
and you must refer to them in the text. Don’t display images without 
making reference to them in the text, or without a caption. Also, 
don’t use images without enough size or resolution. Instead of using 
images that fill up a complete page, just present the bit of the 
image that is enough to illustrate your point. 
Figure 2.1 \ref{fig:frog} %Second Link - should go to Figure 1% 
should be included just after its (paragragph) reference.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{tiger.jpg}
    \caption{Enter Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
%fig:tiger  ?

\subsection{How to include Figures}

First you have to upload the image file from your computer using 
the upload link in the file-tree menu. Then use the includegraphics 
command to include it in your document. Use the figure environment 
and the caption command to add a number and a caption to your figure. 
See the code for Figure \ref{fig:frog} in this section for an 
example.

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. It looks like you're already most of the way to your goal. Real quick: Are you familiar with the LaTeX \label-\ref cross-referencing system? The reason I ask is that your sample code already contains several \label and \ref directives. Moreover, your sample code also loads the hyperref package. Could you maybe be more specific as to what your questions are?

With the hyperref package that you are already using. You should see a linked number in place of  \ref{fig:frog} but only if you have a figure with a frog and the label fig:frog. With only a tiger figure with an unrelated label hardly it could work.

note that you shouldn't need to write Figure 2.1 at all. you should have something like Figure \ref{fig:frogspawn} or whatever where \label{fig:frogspawn} occurs someplace in your source.

After complying with @Fran and @cfr  comments, if you are looking at the formating of hyperlinks as shown on your posted image, simply remove the colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue options passed to hyperref.
